# Prompt user for input in Maven 3 Mojo

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

What's the correct way to prompt the user for input in a Maven 3.3.x Mojo?

My old plugin used this old codehaus plexus utility. What's the replacement for this in Maven 3.3.x?

```
import org.codehaus.plexus.components.interactivity.Prompter;

@Component
protected Prompter prompter;
```

Comment: you simply shouldn't.

Comment: the versions-maven-plugin still uses it in its set goal, https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/versions/SetMojo.java